# Comparing grouped data with a certain row in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

My data looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Mall": ["A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"],
        "Category": ["Milk", "Egg", "Beef", "Egg", "Orange", "Egg"],
        "Price": [5, 10, 15, 9, 7, 11]
    },
    columns=["Mall", "Category", "Price"],
)
df

>>>
    Mall    Category    Price
0   A       Milk        5
1   A       Egg         10
2   B       Beef        15
3   B       Egg         9
4   C       Orange      7
5   C       Egg         11
```

For each mall and category, I would like to compare the difference in price with egg.

In this case:
Price of milk in Mall A - price of egg in Mall A
Price of egg in Mall A - price of egg in Mall A
Price of beef in Mall B - price of egg in Mall B
Price of egg in Mall B - price of egg in Mall B
Price of orange in Mall C - price of egg in Mall C
Price of egg in Mall C - price of egg in Mall C

Expected outcome:

```
    Mall    Category    Price   Price_diff
0   A       Milk        5       -5
1   A       Egg         10      0
2   B       Beef        15      6
3   B       Egg         9       0
4   C       Orange      7       -4      
5   C       Egg         11      0
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For compare by `Egg` repalce non `Egg` values in `Price` to missing values by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and then use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) for repeat `egg price`, last subtract `Price` by [`Series.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html):

```
df['Price_diff'] = (df['Price'].sub(df['Price'].where(df['Category'].eq('Egg'))
                               .groupby(df['Mall']).transform('first')))
print (df)
  Mall Category  Price  Price_diff
0    A     Milk      5        -5.0
1    A      Egg     10         0.0
2    B     Beef     15         6.0
3    B      Egg      9         0.0
4    C   Orange      7        -4.0
5    C      Egg     11         0.0
```

If `Egg` is always second value per groups and each groups contains only 2 values:

```
df['Price_diff'] = df.groupby('Mall')['Price'].diff(-1).fillna(0)
print (df)
  Mall Category  Price  Price_diff
0    A     Milk      5        -5.0
1    A      Egg     10         0.0
2    B     Beef     15         6.0
3    B      Egg      9         0.0
4    C   Orange      7        -4.0
5    C      Egg     11         0.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if I want to calculate the percentage of change? I tried df['Price_diff'] = df['Price'].pct_change(df['Price'].where(df['Category'].eq('Egg')).groupby(df['Mall']).transform('first')) and it did not work.

Comment: @NovaPoi - How looks expected output? or need divide instead `sub` like `(df['Price'].div(df['Price'].where(df['Category'].eq('Egg'))
                               .groupby(df['Mall']).transform('first')))` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby` with `transform`:

```
df['Price_diff'] = df.groupby('Mall')['Price'].transform(lambda x: [x.tolist()[0] - x.tolist()[1], 0])
```

Output:

```
  Mall Category  Price  Price_diff
0    A     Milk      5          -5
1    A      Egg     10           0
2    B     Beef     15           6
3    B      Egg      9           0
4    C   Orange      7          -4
5    C      Egg     11           0
```